# How to find exact match using sed?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

```
sed 's/\<matching pattern\>/replacing pattern/g' filename
```

The above command is what I got from stack overflow. But this command is not working in HP-UX B.11.11 version.

Also i would like to know the answer for the below question? how to find and replace the matching pattern across all files in a directory. Repalced value should be modified/rewritten into the same file and saved.

I was able to match and replace across all files using the below command but was unable to rewrite/save the outputs into the same file.

```
awk 'match($0,/matching pattern/) {gsub(/matching pattern/,"replacing pattern")}1' *
```

Comment: An example would be better. Whhich string you want to replace among all the files?

Comment: this is a simple sed action, what is the error on HP ? Try maybe with option `-e`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu - First SED is taking the matching string as <matchingpattern> and its searching for this pattern. If i have a matching word like <happy> it is replaced with replacing pattern. But if the matching word is happy it is not replaced.

Comment: and with this `sed -e 's/[<]matching pattern[>]/replacing pattern/g' filename` ?

Comment: @NeronLeVelu its again taking the matchin string as <matching pattern> :(

Comment: this is correct, if you want to find `happy`, you don't have to search `<happy>`. What do you want to search exactly ?

Comment: i want to find only "happy" and words like happy123, happyfdsf, happy fdf should not be considered. i need a command similar to grep -w in sed?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through GNU `find` command,

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/match/replace/g' {} \;
```

It would find the files --> match the string--> replace the match --> Save the changes made to that file.

Comment: My bad :( sed -i option is not supported in my unix box. Will there be any other possibility to achieve this?